# How to avoid Chrome Console error Unsafe JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, cross-domain

Chrome display this error in console "Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL https://domain1/app1/ from frame with URL https://domain2/app1/. Domains, protocols and ports must match."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A frame cannot acces the content of another frame if it is not of the same origin. If that is what you're trying to achieve, you cannot work around that issue.

- [Same Origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)

Comment: I can confirm at least that I've found no way to do this. If you're trying to dynamically change the box size to fit the target of the frame, you can do this if you are able to put javascript on the CURRENTLY LOADED target of the frame (users can click on links inside the frame to bring them to other locations.) There's a stack overflow question which addresses this here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5589756/is-there-a-cross-domain-iframe-height-auto-resizer-that-works/6940711

Answer (score 2):

The browser will not allow Javascript to access cross domain, as malicious websites would be able to interact with other sites which would be a huge security concern.

I found this on Google groups, might be worth looking at:

> I believe that dev versions of Chrome
>   currently have support for 
>   Cross-Origin Resource Sharing, which
>   allows hosts that want to to  opt-into
>   cross-origin XHR access 
>   http://dev.w3.org/2006/waf/access-control.
>   You could try that, but  it's pretty
>   bleeding edge, so I'd expect rough
>   patches.