# validate iframe input field from outside the iframe submit button - jquery validator plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I have one html structure

```
<form id="myvalidation">
<iframe>
<form  id="insidevalidation">
<input type="text" name="myname" id="myname" />
</form>
</iframe>
<input type="submit" />

</form>
```

I need to validate input field which is inside the `iframe` but i am not able to find the `name` for validation from outside the iframe.

```
 "myname": {
                            required:true,
                            validEmail:true
                            //onlyNumeric:true
                        },
```

Not sure how to get `myname`from outside the iframe.
please help

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15002652/get-value-of-input-field-inside-an-iframe).

Comment: i want to validate via jquery validator plugin

Comment: What do you mean, *"can't find the `name`"*... you don't know the `name`, or the plugin does not work when you use the `name`?

Answer (score 0):

As long as the `input` has a `name`, you do not need to know the `name` to declare rules using the `.rules()` method.

After initializing the plugin with `.validate()`, you can attach the `.rules()` method to any selector.

```
$('#insidevalidation').validate({ // initialize plugin
    // other options, etc.
    ....
});

$('#insidevalidation input').rules('add', { // attach these rules to FIRST input element
    required: true,
    validEmail: true
});
```

Also note that your submit button is *outside* of the `form` you're trying to validate so it's not going to work as expected.

---

However, my answer assumes that you can use this plugin on a `form` within an `iframe`.  I don't know, and it cannot be tested within an SO snippet or a jsFiddle since the `iframe` is rendering empty.

Comment: my js file is outside the iframe.. how could i simply validate with $('#insidevalidation input')