# Why does contentDocument returns null?

Tags: javascript, svg

I'd like to fill an `svg` file inside inside an `<object>` tag using javascript.

The problem is that `.contentDocument` returns `null`, therefore I can't fill the svg icon.

JSFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/8kf36L0j/16/

I'm on the latest version of Firefox and Chrome, I read lots of other posts about this subject but I couldn't find something usefull to fix this issue.

**HTML**

```
<object id="svg_image_id" type="image/svg+xml" data="http://openclipart.org/people/StudioFibonacci/kitchen-blender.svg"></object>
```

**Javascript**

```
// Alternativ 1
alert(document.getElementById("svg_image_id").contentDocument); // .contentDocument == null ?
document.getElementById("svg_image_id").contentDocument.getElementById("path241").style.fill="red";

// Alternativ 2
var obj = document.querySelector("#svg_image_id");
var svg = obj.contentDocument.querySelector("svg"); // obj.contentDocument == null ?
svg.style.fill="red";
alert(svg);
```

Why is `contentDocument` returning `null` ? How can I fill the svg icon to another color ?

Comment: It is a cross origin issue - [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15002652/get-value-of-input-field-inside-an-iframe/17262334#17262334) could help

Comment: @JaromandaX So if the svg was on my own server it should work ?

Comment: I can't see why not

Comment: use whatever server side language you have - the technique is the important part - you probably have no luck making it work in jsfiddle

Comment: Here is one way to get in jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/Lfhkxkz6/

Answer (score -1):

Make sure u are using the `object` element:

```
<object id="map" type="image/svg+xml">
  <img src="yourfallback.jpg" />
</object>
```

If obtaining a svg from a diffrent domain, use a fetch call

```
const map = document.querySelector('#map');
(async () => {
    const markup = await (await fetch('external-website.com/my.svg')).text();
    const blob = new Blob([markup], { type: 'image/svg+xml' });
    map.data = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

    map.onload = (e) => {
        const doc = map.getSVGDocument();
        doc.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
            console.log(e.target);
        });
    };
})();
```

Comment: They are already using an object element.

Comment: My bad, combining it with fetch call may be a solution in this case