# Getting value from a div element in a online/running site

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So Lets say I have a site like this one http://www.worldtimeserver.com/
and I want somehow to get the value of the time every second and write that value in a .txt file. I was going to use a **OCR**(optical character recognition) software for this job but ..... in the end this option wasn a good choice because I could not rely on exact position of the clock.

Then I started to think "is there a way to inject/put some code in the browser that would do this?". When I inspect the web-page (in Chrome) I saw  that the Div containing the time has an **id="theTime"**. So is there a way to do this? I have some basic experience in JS & DOM ... but this I have no idea how to do or from where to start. Also i would like to point out that I need to rely that the script will do this job for hours and hours and that the value of the clock is set by outside (a server).

Comment: What precisely are you trying to achieve with this? Assuming that a text file full of incrementing values isn't really an end in itself.

Comment: Well this example (with the clock) is just to show as simple and clear what I want to do. My case is different - I have a Field that will show some digits, but the digits will be changing constantly every second and most definitely wont be successive/incrementing. I need this because I want to store the data and after that to analyze it. Yet the site/server allow you to see the data only for the past 1 hour and I need it sometimes to show it for a full day

Comment: The thing you're trying to do in general terms is web crawling/scraping, you should do some research around that.

Answer (score 1):

If the value does not require the browser to refresh to change the value.. you can save it using localstorage and later copy paste it in a txt file

Answer (score 0):

this is a possible duplicate.
[Get value of input field inside an iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15002652/get-value-of-input-field-inside-an-iframe)
use an iframe (you can hide it if you don't want users to see it).