# Get input text value from "iframe"

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, input

firstly sorry for my English.

I have an iframe:

```
<dl class="ctrlUnit">
    <dt>{xen:phrase image_url}:</dt>
    <dd><input type="text" name="redactor_image_link" id="redactor_image_link" class="textCtrl" /></dd>
</dl>
<div style="border: 3px dotted #a0a0a0; overflow: hidden; margin: 15px auto; max-width: 650px;">
                 <iframe src="http://img.uforum.uz" width="650px" height="483px" align="center"style="border: 0px none; margin-left: 0px !important; height: 483px; margin-top: -10px; width: 665px;">
                    Ваш браузер не поддерживает плавающие фреймы!
                </iframe>
        </div>
<dl class="ctrlUnit submitUnit">
    <dt></dt>
    <dd>
        <input type="button" name="upload" class="redactor_modal_btn button primary" id="redactor_image_btn" value="{xen:phrase insert}" />
        <a href="javascript:void(null);" class="redactor_modal_btn redactor_btn_modal_close button">{xen:phrase cancel}</a>
    </dd>
</dl>
```

Via this iframe users can upload image and paste direct URL into the input form manually

After uploading, **http://img.uforum.uz** will redirect to the **http://img.uforum.uz/upload.php**, and in this page needs automatically paste value (URL from iframe input):

```
<input type="text" value="http://img.uforum.uz/images/luqihve4440494.jpg" name="direct" size="50">
```

to second input (which placed not in iframe, but above the iframe code):

```
<dd><input type="text" name="redactor_image_link" id="redactor_image_link" class="textCtrl" /></dd>
```

I don't know JavaScript and need your help)

Thank's in advance.

Comment: you can read this answer, it maybe help you a lot.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15002652/get-value-of-input-field-inside-an-iframe

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get value of input field inside an iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15002652/get-value-of-input-field-inside-an-iframe)

Answer (score -1):

Set id then get it by:

```
var iframetext = document.getElementById("myiframe").innerHTML;
```