# Set input (without id, class or name) value inside iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I need to set a value to an input field that is located (deep) inside an iframe.
This input has no id, name or class.

[image: Code extract]

Is this possible?

I can't simply add an id or the like because the code is coming from an outside source:
[image]

Comment: You can't edit a page that isn't your. It's prohibited btw

Comment: This QA should help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15002652/get-value-of-input-field-inside-an-iframe

Answer (score 0):

If there is only one `<input>` element, you can refer to it by tag name. With jQuery, you would write:

```
$("iframe#sq-postal-code").contents().find('input')
```

Note that this may fail with pages coming from outside, due to [same origin policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) enforced by modern browsers.

[Source](http://simple.procoding.net/2008/03/21/how-to-access-iframe-in-jquery/)