# Mozilla iframe scrolling

Tags: jsp, iframe, cross-browser, mozilla

I have an `iframe` and when the web page is calling inside the scrolling it is not working with `Mozilla Firefox`.

It's working fine in `Internet Explorer` and `Google Chrome`.

```
<iframe name="contentFrame" id="contentFrame" SRC="<c:out value='${CONTENT_FRAME_URL}'/>" margin width=0 marginheight=0 

 vspace=0 hspace=0 scrolling=no WIDTH=780 height="350" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true"
        style="position:absolute;overflow:hidden;border:none;">
</iframe>
```

Why doesn't mozilla firefox support this?

crome interpreted this as

```
<iframe name="contentFrame" id="contentFrame" src="empty.jsp" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" scrolling="no" width="780" height="180%" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" style="position: absolute; overflow: hidden; border: none; height: 1003px;">

                    </iframe>
```

atomatic add some height in style in adjust the size of scroller.
but mozzila not able to do this.

Comment: could you make it work? I get the same issue.

Comment: I resolved the issue by other Mechanism,Will provide you.Hope that you will also resolved.

Comment: @Joar try using following LInk http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9975810/make-iframe-automatically-adjust-height-according-to-the-contents-without-using/9976309#9976309

Comment: Thanks for getting back. Finally I could make it work just as simple as adding "overflow: auto" in my iframe. Works in every browser I tested so far, including firefox

Answer (score 0):

Try using `overflow: auto;` I am wondering why this is working with IE and chrome

Comment: I need side scroller bar not inside iframe. so this solution not required.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting px after width and height value

Like this: width="780px"

Comment: try setting the width and height inside style