# Resize iframe height according to content height

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

I'm trying to resize an iframe according to height and width of it's content(webpage). I've used a code that I found on stack's other answer. For setup of new width, it seems that works but I can't get that height to work and I don't know why.

You can see and edit my example here: http://jsfiddle.net/dzorz/pvtr3/

Here is my HTML:

```
<iframe id="finance-iframe" class="finance-iframe" src="http://wordpress.org" width="100%" height="300px" marginheight="0" frameborder="0" onLoad="autoResize('finance-iframe');"></iframe>
```

and javascript:

```
function autoResize("finance-iframe"){
  var newheight;
  var newwidth;

  if(document.getElementById){
    newheight=document.getElementById("finance-iframe").contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight;
    newwidth=document.getElementById("finance-iframe").contentWindow.document.body.scrollWidth;
  }

  document.getElementById("finance-iframe").height= (newheight) + "px";
  document.getElementById("finance-iframe").width= (newwidth) + "px";
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The solution has been found here already:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9975810/make-iframe-automatically-adjust-height-according-to-the-contents-without-using

Answer (score 8):

There are 4 different properties to look into to get the height of the content in an iFrame.

```
document.documentElement.scrollHeight
document.documentElement.offsetHeight
document.body.scrollHeight
document.body.offsetHeight
```

Sadly they can all give different answers and these are inconsistent between browsers. If you set the body margin to 0 then the `document.body.offsetHeight` gives the best answer. To get the correct value try this function; which is taken from the **[iframe-resizer](https://github.com/davidjbradshaw/iframe-resizer)** library that also looks after keeping the iFrame the correct size when the content changes,or the browser is resized.

```
function getIFrameHeight(){
    function getComputedBodyStyle(prop) {
        function getPixelValue(value) {
            var PIXEL = /^\d+(px)?$/i;

            if (PIXEL.test(value)) {
                return parseInt(value,base);
            }

            var 
                style = el.style.left,
                runtimeStyle = el.runtimeStyle.left;

            el.runtimeStyle.left = el.currentStyle.left;
            el.style.left = value || 0;
            value = el.style.pixelLeft;
            el.style.left = style;
            el.runtimeStyle.left = runtimeStyle;

            return value;
        }

        var 
            el = document.body,
            retVal = 0;

        if (document.defaultView && document.defaultView.getComputedStyle) {
            retVal =  document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(el, null)[prop];
        } else {//IE8 & below
            retVal =  getPixelValue(el.currentStyle[prop]);
        } 

        return parseInt(retVal,10);
    }

    return document.body.offsetHeight +
        getComputedBodyStyle('marginTop') +
        getComputedBodyStyle('marginBottom');
}
```

Answer (score 6):

```
<section id="about" data-type="background" data-speed="10" class="pages">
    <iframe src="index.html" id="demo_frame" align="center" scrolling="no"  frameborder="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0"></iframe>
</section>

<script>
        $('iframe').load(function() {
            this.style.height = this.contentWindow.document.body.offsetHeight + 'px';
        });
</script>
```

Comment: This should be the correct answer. It's the most elegant.

Comment: In my case is not work