# Bootstrap Modal - resize modal based on iframe height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, iframe

I need to resize this `bootstrap` modal based on the height of the `iframe` content because it is dynamic.

Using an `onload` and the following function I am getting nothing.

```
window.resizeIframe = function () {
         var frame = $('#custom-frame');
         var modalHeight = $('#custom-frame').contents().height();
         frame.height(modalHeight);

         $(window).resize(function() {
            frame.height(modalHeight);
         });
      };
```

I've provided a plunker:
http://plnkr.co/edit/eElqXJwvxmpc1XMrdwIK?p=preview

Comment: The link says the Plunk can't be found.

Comment: nah, it's good. try again..

Comment: _Sigh._ I wouldn't lie to you. I would just use JSFiddle if I were you.

Comment: **Update:** Turns out Plunker doesn't work well with work proxies. XMLHttpRequest errors everywhere.

Comment: while this one is (kind of inaccurately) closed - based on Google results for Bootstrap - adding this css to the iframe tag solves the size of the modal: style="min-height: [your preferred pixel height];"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless you set it explicitly using a `height` attribute (which you're not doing), the height of an `<iframe>` defaults to 150px. Before setting the modal height, you'll need to set the `<iframe>` height. Some information in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18765920/resize-iframe-height-according-to-content-height).

Answer (score 2):

Using This:

```
 <div class="media video-container">
                        <iframe width="640" height="390" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/OqP54KZOz0U" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                      </div>
```

And Css is:

```
.video-container {
position: relative;
padding-bottom: 56.25%;
padding-top: 30px;
height: 0;
overflow: hidden;}

.video-container iframe,  .video-container object,  .video-container embed {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;}
```

Comment: could you elaborate on this? Why are you setting the .video-container height to 56.25%?