# Iframe autoresizing height from codebehind in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

My html page is

```
<iframe runat="server" id="iframe1" width="100%" height="100%" scrolling="no"  frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

.cs content in my pageload event

```
iframe1.Attributes["src"] = "http://default.com/";
//iframe1.Attributes["height"] = "100%";
//iframe1.Attributes["width"] = "100%";
iframe1.Attributes.Add("style","width:100%;height:100%;");
```

But its not working

i want to display whole page content but my height of iframe is not taking the height of http://default.com/

Comment: @Ela its not working...showing me scrolling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how to autoresize iframe on .cs page but It's another option like put your iframe in datalist control like...

```
<asp:DataList ID="dtlhtml" runat="server" Width="100%">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <iframe src='<%#Eval("html") %>' width="713" id="iframe1" 
                        frameborder="0" onLoad="autoResize 'iframe1');">
                    </iframe>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

Put javascript code as...

```
<script language="JavaScript">
function autoResize(id) 
{
    var newheight;
    var newwidth;
    if (document.getElementById(id))
    {
        newheight = document.getElementById(id).contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight;
        newwidth = document.getElementById(id).contentWindow.document.body.scrollWidth;
    }
    document.getElementById(id).height = (newheight) + "px";
    document.getElementById(id).width = (newwidth) + "px";
}
</script>
```

And put on .cs page.

```
DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
dt1.Columns.Add("html");
DataRow dr = dt1.NewRow();
dr["html"] = "";//Any dynamic url path
dt1.Rows.Add(dr);
dtlhtml.DataSource = dt1;
dtlhtml.DataBind();
```

**NOTE:
*This will not work in local host ..please try it on online.***

Answer (score 0):

I assume you don't want 'scrolling', so why not disable it?

```
<iframe src="/default.asp" width="100%" height="100%" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

or try

```
iframe1.Attributes.Add("scrolling","no");
```

Edit: Try

```
PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<iframe src='mypage.aspx' width='100%' height='100%' scrolling='no'></iframe>"));
```

or

```
iframe1.Attributes["src"] = "http://www.asp.net";
```

Comment: I want to give src path on .cs page

Comment: should i have to take PlaceHolder???and have to remove iframe from my html code??

Comment: Typically if you want to add controls to a page like you are doing then people use a placeholder and insert controls into it

Comment: Come to think of it, what exactly is iframe1 ?

Comment: Read this SO post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9975810/make-iframe-automatically-adjust-height-according-to-the-contents-without-using

Comment: if the iframe src is given statically in html page than it will easily resize its page as javascript is call and seems the content of iframe src....but here all javascript is call before iframe get its src OR all javascript is call before it goes to page load so the javascript will not be helpfull for me

Comment: Try adding the iframe during the PreRender event

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using `runat="server"` so you can access the attributes like height and width from code behind.
Try

### Updated Answer

```
iFrame1.Attributes.Add("height","100%");
iFrame1.Attributes.Add("width","100%");
set scrolling ="no" inside tag as suggested by Paul
```

Comment: Its not taking as iFrame1.Width="100%" and i had tried as shown in my question