# Is there a way to make an Iframe expandable as needed?

Tags: c#, javascript, html, asp.net, iframe

Is there a way to make an Iframe expandable as needed? I have a web page with an Iframe to a second web page on a same  server. The second web page has an expandable table. What I would like is when someone views the second page throught the Iframe and clicks on the table to expand, the Iframe will also expand to fit the size.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
window.onload = function() {
var f = document.getElementById("mainframe");
function resize() {
var h = "";
var w = "";
if (f.contentDocument) {
h = f.contentDocument.documentElement.offsetHeight + 20 + "px";
(f.contentDocument.documentElement,"").getProperty Value

("width");
} else if (f.contentWindow) {
h = f.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + 5 + "px";
} else {
return;
}
f.setAttribute("height",h);
f.parentNode.setAttribute("height",h);
}
if (window.addEventListener) {
f.onload = resize;
} else if (f.attachEvent) {
f.attachEvent("onload", resize);
} else {
return;
}
resize();
}
//]]>
</script>

<iframe name="frm" id="mainframe" src="URL HERE" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="no" scrolling="no" target="_self" height="150"></iframe>
```

And here's the HTML code:

```
<a href="URL OF PAGE" target="content">Name Of Page</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the page is in same domain in that case following solution should work.

[Make iframe automatically adjust height according to the contents without using scrollbar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9975810/make-iframe-automatically-adjust-height-according-to-the-contents-without-using)