# iFrame Height Auto (CSS)

Tags: html, css, iframe, height

I am having problems with my iframe. I really want the frame to auto adjust heights according to the content within the iframe. I really want to do this via the CSS without javascript. However, I will use javascript if I have too.

I've tried `height: 100%;` and `height: auto;`, etc. I just don't know what else to try!

Here is my CSS. For the frame...

```css
#frame {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 860px;
  height: 100%;
}
```

And then for the frame's page.

```css
#wrap {
  float: left;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 780px;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: justify;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #6BA070;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
}
```

The page's coding looks like this...

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" ��         "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" > 

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>...</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div id="container">    
    <div id="header">
    </div>

  <div id="navigation"> 
    <a href="/" class="navigation">home</a>
    <a href="about.php" class="navigation">about</a>
    <a href="fanlisting.php" class="navigation">fanlisting</a>
    <a href="reasons.php" class="navigation">100 reasons</a>
    <a href="letter.php" class="navigation">letter</a>
  </div>
  <div id="content" >
    <h1>Update Information</h1>
    <iframe name="frame" id="frame" src="http://website.org/update.php" allowtransparency="true" frameborder="0"></iframe>
  </div>
  <div id="footer">
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Please note that the URL within the iframe is different then the website the iframe will be displayed on. However, I have access to both websites.

Can anyone help?

Comment: That won't work. I think you will have to use JS somehow.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9975810/make-iframe-automatically-adjust-height-according-to-the-contents-without-using

Comment: Try this on  #frame width:100%; max-width:860px;

Answer (score 43):

I had this same issue but found the following that works great:

The key to creating a responsive YouTube embed is with padding and a container element, which allows you to give it a fixed aspect ratio. You can also use this technique with most other iframe-based embeds, such as slideshows.

Here is what a typical YouTube embed code looks like, with fixed width and height:

```
 <iframe width="560" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/yCOY82UdFrw" 
 frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

It would be nice if we could just give it a 100% width, but it won't work as the height remains fixed. What you need to do is wrap it in a container like so (note the class names and removal of the width and height):

```
 <div class="container">
 <iframe src="//www.youtube.com/embed/yCOY82UdFrw" 
 frameborder="0" allowfullscreen class="video"></iframe>
 </div>
```

And use the following CSS:

```
 .container {
    position: relative;
     width: 100%;
     height: 0;
     padding-bottom: 56.25%;
 }
 .video {
     position: absolute;
     top: 0;
     left: 0;
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
 }
```

Here is the page I found the solution on:

https://www.h3xed.com/web-development/how-to-make-a-responsive-100-width-youtube-iframe-embed

Depending on your aspect ratio, you will probably need to adjust the `padding-bottom: 56.25%;` to get the height right.

Comment: Please note that <iframe frameborder=""> was deprecated in HTML5.

Comment: This just makes the height static relative to the width it doesn't make the height automatically adjust for the height of the content.

Comment: So many upvotes, but this doesn't accomplish what op asked for.

Answer (score 12):

This is my PURE CSS solution :)

Add, scrolling yes to your iframe.

```
<iframe src="your iframe link" width="100%" scrolling="yes" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

The trick :)

```
<style>
    html, body, iframe { height: 100%; }
    html { overflow: hidden; }
</style>
```

You don't need to worry about responsiveness :)

Comment: @P.James: did it *actually* expand the iframe for you? I'd be shocked...

Comment: On the time I comment this, this is actually working. Or it depends on your structure. But this do the trick with me.

Comment: changing html with an additional attribute is not pure css

Comment: Also, this doesn't work. The iframe stays the same height.

Answer (score 4):

[hjpotter92](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1190388/hjpotter92)

> Add this to your  section:
>
> ```
> <script>
>   function resizeIframe(obj) {
>     obj.style.height = obj.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + 'px';
>   }
> </script>
> ```
>
> And change your iframe to this:
>
> ```
> <iframe src="..." frameborder="0" scrolling="no" onload="resizeIframe(this)" />
> ```

It is posted [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9975810/make-iframe-automatically-adjust-height-according-to-the-contents-without-using)

It does however use javascript, but it is simple and easy to use code that will fix your problem.

Comment: I have a similar solution working for an iframe with source within the same domain as the host, but where iframe host and source are from different domains, this solution may not work because of cross-site scripting restrictions.

Comment: I've had better results getting the `scrollHeight` of `document.scrollingElement` than `document.body`.

Comment: This doesn't work. There are security restrictions on iFrames.

Answer (score 3):

@SweetSpice, use position as absolute in place of relative. It will work

```
#frame{
overflow: hidden;
width: 860px;
height: 100%;
position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: you should add position:relative to the parent

Comment: Yes, **position: relative;** is already there in **.container** class - @Mawardy

Answer (score 0):

```
 <div id="content" >
    <h1>Update Information</h1>
    <div id="support-box">
        <div id="wrapper">
            <iframe name="frame" id="frame" src="http://website.org/update.php" allowtransparency="true" frameborder="0"></iframe>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
 #support-box {
        width: 50%;
        float: left;
        display: block;
        height: 20rem; /* is support box height you can change as per your requirement*/
        background-color:#000;
    }
    #wrapper {
        width: 90%;
        display: block;
        position: relative;
        top: 50%;
        transform: translateY(-50%);
         background:#ddd;
       margin:auto;
       height:100px; /* here the height values are automatic you can leave this if you can*/

    }
    #wrapper iframe {
        width: 100%;
        display: block;
        padding:10px;
        margin:auto;
    }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/umd2ahce/1/

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Comment: Thank you for your valuable suggestion. Yes you are right  "answering the question for readers in the future". I will try to fine tune my answer

Answer (score -1):

You have to use `absolute` position along with your desired height.
in your CSS, do the following:

```
#id-of-iFrame {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: height:100%; — this says the height of the iframe should be 100% of the width of the containing element in the iframe's host page (not, for example, 100% of the height of the content of the iframe's source page). In any case, I have tried this, and it does not work for me.

Comment: @MatthewSlyman 100% of the *width*?  Assume you meant "height" there

Comment: No, percentages are treated not as a percentage of the same variable or similarly oriented dimension within the root or parent object (check which if you need clarification)... Rather they are treated (unintuitively) effectively as a unit of measurement, defined by width of container (?) divided by 100. If you want to define any dimension (height or width or anything else) by the height of a parent object, you will need to use for example "vh" units instead.

Comment: @MatthewSlyman I don't think that's true: https://codepen.io/Alynva/pen/OJjpwPy

Comment: Interesting counter-example! I distinctly remember struggling with this issue some years ago, so maybe something has changed, or the root cause of the issue was different to what I surmised, or the issue occurs under different conditions.

Answer (score -1):

You should note that **div** tag behaves like nothing and just let you to put something in it. It means that if you insert a paragraph with 100 lines of text within a **div** tag, it shows all the text but its height won't change to contain all the text.

So you have to use a CSS & HTML trick to handle this issue. This trick is very simple. you must use an **empty div tag** with ***class="clear"*** and then you will have to add this class to your CSS. Also note that your have **#wrap** in your CSS file but you don't have any tag with this id. In summary you have to change you code to something like below:

HTML Code:

```
    <!-- Change "id" from "container" to "wrap" -->
    <div id="wrap">    
        <div id="header">
        </div>

        <div id="navigation"> 
            <a href="/" class="navigation">home</a>
            <a href="about.php" class="navigation">about</a>
            <a href="fanlisting.php" class="navigation">fanlisting</a>
            <a href="reasons.php" class="navigation">100 reasons</a>
            <a href="letter.php" class="navigation">letter</a>
        </div>
        <div id="content" >
            <h1>Update Information</h1>
            <iframe name="frame" id="frame" src="http://website.org/update.php" allowtransparency="true" frameborder="0"></iframe>

            <!-- Add this line -->
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="footer">
        </div>

        <!-- Add this line -->
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
```

And also add this line to your CSS file:

```
.clear{ display: block; clear: both;}
```

Comment: This explanation of `div` height isn't right - it's describing what happens when an element contains floated children (the height collapses). In the example (`div` containing 100 lines of text), the `div` would grow in height to contain all the text.

Answer (score -4):

According to **[this post](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/forums/showthread.php?46273-I-Made-a-Fluid-IFrame)**

You need to add the `!important` css modifier to your height percentages.

Hope this helps.

Comment: The heights work just fine without the `!important` tag. That doesn't change the auto though.

Comment: Oh I guess I misunderstood your question. Didn't you state that the height:100% wasn't working properly? Did you try that without using 'auto' at all? @SweetSpice

Comment: yes. I tried auto AND 100%. Both separately. I also tried both with the `!important` tag and without.