# Automatically set iFrame height to that of content, HTML5 or CSS only

Tags: html, css, iframe

## **Explanation**

I've run into an issue in my website; I have conflicting style sheets. Instead of manually changing each class, I'd like to take a different approach, which I hopefully could apply to other projects in the long run. After doing some research, creating a seperate web page and utilizing an IFrame on the original webpage seems best, however I wouldn't want users to notice any difference. Because of this it would have to be seamless, and have the height automatically adjust to that of the content on the external web page. In theory I could apply CSS to make the iFrame seamless, and set the height to either `height:100%;` or `height:auto;` which would ideally make the iFrame height that of the content.

However, both  height settings don't affect the content inside the iFrame itself but by the container of the iFrame, meaning `height:100%;` would take up 100% of webpage it's being displayed on. I've seen answers to similar questions, however they all involve javascript for the solution. I'd like to avoid javascript, as not only am I not educated in javascript but I personally believe that there can be another way without involving another programming language.

**TLDR** In other words, I would like to create a completely seamless iFrame, displaying the contents of a different webpage. The height should automatically adjust to that of the content inside it. The end result should implement another webpage seamlessly without users noticing it as any different to the rest of the web page.

## **Code**

I found a [helpful question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24157940/iframe-height-auto-css) which helped me out writing the code, however it doesn't fully work as intended. The iFrame completely replaces all of web page instead of adding onto it (Example below). I didn't paste in my exact code, I trimmed it down to only keep the relevant parts.

**CSS**

```
html, body, iframe { height: 100%; }
html { overflow: hidden; }
```

**HTML**

```
<iframe src="https://example.com/"  width="100%" scrolling="yes" frameborder="0">
<h2>Lorem Ispum</h2>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse porttitor vitae est finibus dapibus. Maecenas convallis ante turpis. Pellentesque eget interdum mi. Sed scelerisque rhoncus eleifend. Quisque tortor massa, molestie non odio et, tristique placerat enim. Fusce id massa eleifend, placerat massa at, auctor purus. Cras posuere augue et dolor convallis, at vulputate elit tincidunt. Morbi ut imperdiet orci. Donec commodo est metus, sit amet laoreet nisl mattis a. Sed magna nunc, molestie sed risus vel, faucibus euismod orci. Mauris bibendum, quam a lacinia euismod, ex mi laoreet odio, a tincidunt nisl neque in sapien</p>
```

## **Output**

```css
html, body, iframe { height: 100%; }
html { overflow: hidden; }
```

```html
<iframe src="https://example.com/"  width="100%" scrolling="yes" frameborder="0">
<h2>Lorem Ispum</h2>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse porttitor vitae est finibus dapibus. Maecenas convallis ante turpis. Pellentesque eget interdum mi. Sed scelerisque rhoncus eleifend. Quisque tortor massa, molestie non odio et, tristique placerat enim. Fusce id massa eleifend, placerat massa at, auctor purus. Cras posuere augue et dolor convallis, at vulputate elit tincidunt. Morbi ut imperdiet orci. Donec commodo est metus, sit amet laoreet nisl mattis a. Sed magna nunc, molestie sed risus vel, faucibus euismod orci. Mauris bibendum, quam a lacinia euismod, ex mi laoreet odio, a tincidunt nisl neque in sapien</p>
```

## **Desired Output**

To show you the desired output, I downloaded the webpage from the iFrame and set css rules to simulate what I want. This is not an actual solution.

```css
    body {
        background-color: #f0f0f2;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;

    }
    #iFrame {
        width: 600px;
        margin: 5em auto;
        padding: 50px;
        background-color: #fff;
        border-radius: 1em;
        font-family: "Open Sans", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    }
    a:link, a:visited {
        color: #38488f;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    @media (max-width: 700px) {
        body {
            background-color: #fff;
        }
        #iFrame {
            width: auto;
            margin: 0 auto;
            border-radius: 0;
            padding: 1em;
        }
    }
    #Desired {
      background-color: white;
    }
```

```html
<div id="iFrame">
    <h1>Example Domain</h1>
    <p>This domain is established to be used for illustrative examples in documents. You may use this
    domain in examples without prior coordination or asking for permission.</p>
    <p><a href="http://www.iana.org/domains/example">More information...</a></p>
</div>
<div id="Desired">
  <h2>Lorem Ispum</h2>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse porttitor vitae est finibus dapibus. Maecenas convallis ante turpis. Pellentesque eget interdum mi. Sed scelerisque rhoncus eleifend. Quisque tortor massa, molestie non odio et, tristique placerat enim. Fusce id massa eleifend, placerat massa at, auctor purus. Cras posuere augue et dolor convallis, at vulputate elit tincidunt. Morbi ut imperdiet orci. Donec commodo est metus, sit amet laoreet nisl mattis a. Sed magna nunc, molestie sed risus vel, faucibus euismod orci. Mauris bibendum, quam a lacinia euismod, ex mi laoreet odio, a tincidunt nisl neque in sapien</p>
</div>
```

Thank you everyone, I looked forward to hearing what you have to say.

**EDIT** Reworded post

Comment: Please post your code

Comment: The thing with iframes is that they contain a canvas of their own, which you have no control over from the outside. And in fact, that is the reason why you want to use iframes: because your existing CSS cannot influence them! So the answer is no, and you have two possibilities: either do use a bit of JS to communicate between the iframes and the main page, or try to rework your existing CSS so that you can use divs after all.