# Auto height iframe to content

Tags: iframe, height

just cant figure out how to get the below code to auto adjust the hight, dependant on the path in "src". As i dont want hard code the height as the src path may change. I have tried various js methods, but none seem to work.

```
<iframe src="C:\" height="200" width="100%"></iframe>
```

I have done the styles inline, but will be managing all styles in a css file.

Help.

Comment: please provide as some of your codes so that we can analyze..

Comment: Sorry, did add the code, but it got striped out. Will add now.

Comment: Code now added, very basic code at that.

Comment: why the `src="C:\"`? What are you working for?

Comment: Work for a service desk and want a webpage to show all our documents, etc, currently, its a manual process to add any new folder or documents, where as if I can get an iframe showing the content of the folder, we wont have to update the htm page.  There trouble is the iframe needs to be auto size so it will always show all the folders\files in the folder.  Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Just tried to add image of what its currently doing, but it wont allow me.

Comment: maybe you are looking for this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9975810/make-iframe-automatically-adjust-height-according-to-the-contents-without-using

Comment: yeah it won't allow you coz your reputation don't met the required for you to post an image.

Comment: Already ready that thread and none of the soltions work.  Have read some many threads and think the issue might lay with the code not being able to detect the boundries of the, content.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use JavaScript to adjust an iFrame to match the size of the content. Check out this library that will watch to content in the iFrame and keep the size upto date.

https://github.com/davidjbradshaw/iframe-resizer

Comment: Hi David, I had previously looked at your resizer, but hadnt tried it.  Just downloaded it, updated the line <iframe src="c:\" width="100%" scrolling="no"></iframe> in the example\index.html file to c:\ and the content of the c:\ drive is visible, but the window doesnt resize.  Am i missing anything?

Answer (score 1):

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function resizeIframe(obj) {
obj.style.height = obj.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + 'px';
}
</script>

<iframe  src="http://stackoverflow.com/" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" id="iframe" onload='javascript:resizeIframe(this);' />
```

Comment: Great..Working fine :)