# iFrame PDF Scrolling Based on Content Height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

```
<div id="iframeTestID"> //abritrarily set to 100% w/h
  <iframe src="somePDFLink"></iframe> //I want the PDF loaded to scroll if it is longer than 100% of the screen
</div>
```

I'm trying to get the iframe to scroll based on the content inside of it. Currently I've had no luck assigning heights to the parent div and the iframe. The best I can get to happen is to scroll to the bottom of the parent's height. It is as though I cannot calculate the height of the content loaded by the iframe, but rather just calculate the height assigned to the iframe box. Is what I'm trying to do impossible?

Comment: I'm not sure. Does ist work this way: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9975810/make-iframe-automatically-adjust-height-according-to-the-contents-without-using

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar for also pdf. It worked in android, ios and windows phone 7/8. Here is my code:

```
<iframe id="identifier" src="urltopdf" style="width: 100%; height: 1000px; border: medium none;visibility: visible;"></iframe>
```

I have it inside a data-role content div, so it takes width from webbrowser. I had no luck determining height of pdf, so just put a big value and it will resize. In my case, there is no more white space after pdf.

Also you could use google reader:

```
<a href="http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&amp;url=urltopdf.PDF" data-transition="slidedown" class="ui-link-inherit"></a>
```

Comment: Using your code, the height did not size. I entered in height: 1000px, which was not long enough, so I switched it to 10000px, which was far too long. It doesn't appear to be sizing to the content of the PDF.

Comment: umm... that is strange. I have 3 pages using that right now. Are you using jquery or jquery mobile?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this by using these two libraries together.

- http://davidjbradshaw.github.io/iframe-resizer/
- https://github.com/davidjbradshaw/iframe-resizer