# Fitting an iframe into content

Tags: html, css, iframe

I have created an HTML page (e.g.cars) which is to be loaded in another HTML (main) page using `<iframe>`.

I have succeeded in doing so but each the time the content changes in the cars HTML, the `iframe` size remains the same which really outlooks the webpage.

I have [pictures on Imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hMnI2.png) for you guys to understand (zoom 25% for you to see the page wholly).

Comment: Any images ? I can't see anything here

Comment: sorry i couldnt upload the pic bkoz i need reputation :(

Comment: Share your code and please explain a little bit more on what you want to achieve...

Comment: here you go,
i used my facebook account to upload the pic plz help me guys

Comment: https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=1494681160825140&set=a.1457233441236579.1073741830.100008498104091&type=1

Comment: ok i`ll try this and let you knw

Comment: i`ll try this and let you knw...have you looked at the pic? use the facebook link

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/153152/resizing-an-iframe-based-on-content

Comment: no it didnt work..can i have a way to send you the coding and the html page so that you can understand

Comment: https://github.com/davidjbradshaw/iframe-resizer .... Go to this link... download the plugin... and check the example folder... it is working perfectly...

Comment: ok saswata :) i am trying it now and will let you knw that i appreciate your help

Comment: saswata i am having trouble understanding how to use the iframeresizer

Comment: i am a noob in this....what do have to do? can you explain in steps about how to link the scripts to my html and the iframe.. thks plz i really need this, it`s for a project

Comment: Added comment in answer, any further comment please do it there, with the answers

Answer (score 0):

Similar answer can be found here: [Make iframe automatically adjust height according to the contents without using scrollbar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9975810/make-iframe-automatically-adjust-height-according-to-the-contents-without-using)

Check this also, https://github.com/davidjbradshaw/iframe-resizer, download the plugin and then go to example folder.Run index.html, and see/change the content in frame.content. It is working perfectly.

Comment: Add these at bottom of your page: <script type="text/javascript" src="js/iframeResizer.min.js"></script> (add this file to your js folder). Along with the other script (js library file and other piece of code) check the html. For iframe page please check the html by editing the page...