# how to resize the iframe while on the same page, based on the content?

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress, iframe

the main reason i want this, is that I don't want to use the scrollbar, I want it to be hidden;

(i use wordpress): i have an iframe from Zoho recruiting embeded in my website. the content of the iframe is 100px at first, but when a job description is opened in the iframe, the content will now be 800px.

however, if no job description is opened, i want the footer to be right under the iframe content (and in the event of a user opening a job description, the page would get larger, to fit the content)

for example you can check it here: http://atracore.com/jobs_test/

Comment: If you want the height of the iframe to be as of it's content height, why not using height as 100% OR 'auto'?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make iframe automatically adjust height according to the contents without using scrollbar?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9975810/make-iframe-automatically-adjust-height-according-to-the-contents-without-using)

Comment: I have found similar question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/819416/adjust-width-height-of-iframe-to-fit-with-content-in-it][1]

Comment: @Nachiketha shu - i tried using the 100% or auto height, but it does not work :(  check it here:  http://atracore.com/jobs_test/