# How to embedded Instagram in a specific language?

Tags: javascript, html, instagram, social-networking, embedding

Embedding Instagram photos is simple enough, simply add an iframe with `/embed/` at the end of the URL like this:

```
https://www.instagram.com/p/BA1wL_MqzTV/embed/
```

But how can I force the UI (the follow/like buttons) to be a specific language like portuguese?

Answer (score 2):

Instagram's embed detects the language from the user's browser. And this is a good solution because users frequently use their browsers on their preferred languages.

But to force the response to be an specific language, you should change **accept-language** request header using a CURL (I'm afraid that is not possible using only an iframe and even using AJAX because of cross-domain security issues).

If you want to verify by yourself try changing the default language and reload the page containing the embed. On Google Chrome you should go to ***Settings***, type ***Language*** on the Search Settings input box and then click on the ***"Language and input settings..."*** button. Add the language and reorder to ensure the preferred one on the top.

[image]

*(On Safari it's not possible unless you change the system language).*

Now you can use **Developer Tools** (Cmd+Option+i for mac users), on **Network** tab to verify headers sent to the server. Note that **pt** is the first language of my **accept-language** header now (on *Request Headers* group). Instagram's response is now in Portuguese ("***Seguir***" instead of "***Follow***").

[image]

[image]

If you still want to force the language despite of the user browser's default, you should implement a CURL on your server changing ***accept-language*** header and configure your iframe src to it. PHP working example below.

***File: myURL.php***

```
$url = $_GET["url"];

$request_headers = array();
$request_headers[] = 'accept-language: pt,en-US;q=0.8'; // Portuguese response first

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $request_headers); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
print_r($output);
```

***HTML:***

```
<iframe src='myUrl.php?url=https://https://www.instagram.com/p/BA1wL_MqzTV/embed/'></iframe>
```

I believe it's a good idea to read Instagram API. There are another ways to do it (oembed and shortcode). Maybe you should consider it.

> https://www.instagram.com/developer/embedding/

The last detail: You will probably need a way to make iframe height equal to the content height. You should look this Stack Overflow question:

> [Make iframe automatically adjust height according to the contents without using scrollbar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9975810/make-iframe-automatically-adjust-height-according-to-the-contents-without-using)

Good luck!

Comment: Yeah I was aware of the accept-language header, but I was hoping to avoid creating a proxy on my server. Besides that all of these solutions would break the user interaction part (the follow button for example) due to CORS. I guess I either have to live with this issue or use the shortcode url to fetch the image and do not provide the interactions functionality.

Comment: Another (harder) option is to fetch photo from API and then provide Like and Comment functionalities using your personalized buttons, calling API methods. For this you should ask Instagram to review your app and grant like and comment permissions.