# ASP:NET MVC: How can I render two styles in one page without any overlaps of CSS classes?

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net

I am working on a web based application that generates documents with some data.
I have a new feature in the document generator, you can paste an Atlassian Confluence (in our company we use this as wiki) link in a textbox and on save the content from this specific page will appear in the document.

**1. Problem:** I have no possibility to get row data from the API of Atlassian Confluence without CSS-Classes.

**2. Problem:** I use in the document generator Bootstrap 3 and Atlassian Confluence use some Bootstrap classes too.
This means: The Atlassian Confluence stylesheet recolor and resize the element on my page and I cannot create a new stylesheet for the content from Confluence because there are some special things and I don’t have the time to do that.

**Question**: Is there any possibility or workaround to fix this problem with the options of ASP.NET and Razor?

Comment: when you save the data pasted in (presumably this is what contains the CSS references?), then strip out anything that's a CSS reference (either `<style>` sections or `<link rel="stylesheet"...` elements) from the submitted markup.

Comment: @ADyson you paste a link of the website in the textbox example: `wiki.mycompany.xyz/mynewpage.html` and then I create a call to the API and get back `HTML` with the styleclasses and style-tags. I dont want create a own stylesheet or a filter for the Confluence-Stylesheet because I have no time. But when there is no choise I will do that

Comment: ok, then you could strip the CSS references from the HTML you get back before you display it. Same process as I suggested, just different source of the HTML. Regular expressions would probably be a good tool to do this, or a HTML parser that can manipulate the DOM. You could even do it in Javascript just before you display the content.

Comment: @ADyson that sounds nice thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution for my Case:**

I created a new `cshtml` Page called "WikiContent". In this Page I render the Content from Attlasian Confluence with the Styling from Confluence. In my Document Page I created an `<iframe>` which renders the Page "WikiContent" with some Parameters.

I used the Answer from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9976309/6383213) Question to style and resize the `<iframe>` with JavaScript. I also added a Width of 100% to the `<iframe>`.