# iframe height not working properly?

Tags: css

I am trying to fit an iframe properly inside this div. Here's what it looks like right now:

[image]

How do I adjust the iframe's height so you can see the whole video. Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make iframe automatically adjust height according to the contents without using scrollbar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9975810/make-iframe-automatically-adjust-height-according-to-the-contents-without-using)

Comment: Either go on google search it or make it fix size

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please review [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). What have you already tried yourself to do this? This isn't a coding or tutoring service. You are expected to ***research your issue and make a good attempt to write the code yourself*** before posting. Then if you get stuck on something *specific*, come back and include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and a summary of what you tried, so we can help.

Comment: Please edit your post and add your  HTML and CSS.

Answer (score 0):

After you grab the iframe from YouTube:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" 
src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/RFaqnamTfm8" 
frameborder="0" allowfullscreen>
</iframe>
```

Just increase the height property until you get the desired effect, which should do the trick.