# How can I refer a library only to a specific part of the HTML?

Tags: html, css

I have the following code, which I found from a tutorial

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/meyer- 
 reset/2.0/reset.min.css">
```

and I would like to include it only to a specific part of my code and not the entire HTML file, is that possible?

Right now it's on the top of my code and it affects the entire page while I want it to affect only some things inside a div. Placing it inside the div doesn't seem to matter.

Comment: As a hacky solution, use iFrame for that part of your page!

Comment: why not just manually reset the elements you want? for example by applying margin 0 and padding 0 to those specific elements.

Answer (score 3):

instead of linking a stylesheet, use import and apply it as scoped style:

```
<div>
    <style scoped>
        @import "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/meyer-reset/2.0/reset.min.css";
    </style>
</div>
```

As the `scoped` is [no more supported by many browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLStyleElement/scoped), if you had browser support problems, use [Jquery Scoped Plugin](https://github.com/thingsinjars/jQuery-Scoped-CSS-plugin) instead.

As a hacky solution, use iFrame for that part of your page however if you want to apply `css-reset` on main parts of page as body margins or scrollbars, this will not help. This is a simple sample of **main page** and **subPage** using iframe:

main page:

```
<html>
    <body>
       Main Content part 1
       <iframe src="subPage.html" style="border:0;width:100%;">
       Main Content part 2
    </body>
</html>
```

Source of iframe (subPage.html):

```
<html>
    <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/meyer-reset/2.0/reset.min.css">
    </head>

    <body>
       Styled content goes here.
    </body>
</html>
```

Finally if you have dynamic content and can not determine the height of iframe, please refer to [this Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9975810/make-iframe-automatically-adjust-height-according-to-the-contents-without-using)

Comment: Could you please provide an example using iFrame on this case?