# Iframe Resizing Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am loading a dynamic into the IFrame. and also resizing the iframe according to form size using following code:

Javascript:

```
function iframeLoaded(i) {
    var iFrameID = document.getElementById(i);
    if (iFrameID) {
        iFrameID.height = "";
        iFrameID.height = iFrameID.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + "px";
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="row ">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div>
            <iframe id="CustomFormIframe" onload="iframeLoaded(this.id)" style="width:100%!important;min-height:150px; background-color:white;" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

But for large form, iframe doesn't resized properly. don't show full form.

[image: Issue Related Iframe]

Comment: When is the `iframeLoaded` function called? It seems like you resize the `iframe` before it is fully loaded.

Comment: i called it on onload event of frame

Comment: Can you try using jQuery: `$(i).height($(i).contents().height());`

Comment: Not working.. Even iframe is not resizing

Comment: Can you add the complete code in your answer? (involved HTML and javascript)

Comment: Please check html above

Comment: What browser are you using? This event `onload="iframeLoaded(this.id)"` will not work on all browsers...

Comment: using google chrome

Answer (score 0):

here is the https://stackoverflow.com/a/9976309 that may be ease your task that you want to do.

**OR**

Only change made is resetting height to 0 on every load in order to enable some browsers to decrease height.

Add this to  tag:

```js
  function resizeIframe(obj){
     obj.style.height = 0;
     obj.style.height = obj.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + 'px';
  }
```

```
<iframe onload='resizeIframe(this)'></iframe>
```

**OR**

```html
<iframe id="form-iframe" src="iframe1form.html" style="margin:0; width:100%; height:150px; border:none; overflow:hidden;" scrolling="no" onload="AdjustIframeHeightOnLoad()"></iframe>
```

Insert JavaScript below the iframe.

Put this JavaScript somewhere below the iframe. It may be down at the end of the page and/or imported from an external file.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
function AdjustIframeHeightOnLoad() { document.getElementById("form-iframe").style.height = document.getElementById("form-iframe").contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + "px"; }
function AdjustIframeHeight(i) { document.getElementById("form-iframe").style.height = parseInt(i) + "px"; }
</script>
```