# Getting the Window Height of an Embedded Tableau Dashboard

Tags: javascript, iframe, tableau-api

After my dashboard initializes and is fully loaded, I need to get the window height of the embed inside the `iframe`. Ideally, I'd like to get `innerHeight` inside of `onFirstInteractive`, but am unable to do so.

```js
function initViz() {
    var containerDiv = document.getElementById("vizContainer");
    var url = "http://public.tableau.com/views/RegionalSampleWorkbook/Storms";

    var options = {
        onFirstInteractive: function() {           
            // How do I get the height of the rendered contents?
        }
    };

    var viz = new tableau.Viz(containerDiv, url, options);
}
```

Comment: Did you try `this.contentWindow.document.body.scrollWidth` and `this.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight`? If the code is called inside the iFrame, then that's how you get the window size.

Comment: @ChristosLytras `this` is unfortunately undefined.

Comment: This is a different question but check te answers, it might help...obj.contentWindow.document.documentElement.scrollHeight. 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9975810/make-iframe-automatically-adjust-height-according-to-the-contents-without-using

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Subscribe to the `VIZ_RESIZE` event, it provides the new dimensions of the `iframe` on initialization and resize:

```
viz.addEventListener(tableau.TableauEventName.VIZ_RESIZE, function(event) {
    console.log(event.getAvailableSize());
});
```

Which gives the following:

[image: console]

When the `iframe` appears like this:

[image: iframe]

If you absolutely want to retrieve the information in `onFirstInteractive`, you can do this:

```
onFirstInteractive: function(viz) {           
    const iframeStyle = viz.$1._impl.$1h.style;
    const { height, width } = iframeStyle;
    console.log({ height, width });
}
```

But it's a little bit hacky because this solution uses properties that are not supposed to be public, so this kind of code may break on future Tableau JS library updates.

Comment: Impressive. Thank you.

Comment: Hi, i tried this approach but i am getting width = 100% and height=100%, any ideas how I can get both in px?