# Is there a way to add/display bloxs in streamlit?

Tags: python, streamlit

> [Bloxs](https://github.com/mljar/bloxs) is a simple python package that helps you display information in an attractive way (formed in blocks). Perfect for building dashboards, reports and apps in the notebook.
>
> It works with: Jupyter Notebook, Google Colab, Deepnote, Kaggle Notebook

```
B([
    B(1999, "Percent change!", percent_change=10),
    B("", "Works with emojis"),
    B("68%", "Loading progress", progress=68),
    B(1234, "Bloxs in notebook!")
])
```

[image]

How to use the **bloxes** in **streamlit**?

I have tried with `st.pyplot`, and with `streamlit HTML component` but not able to add in **streamlit** app.

Is there a way to add these bloxs in Streamlit?

Comment: how did you try it with HTML component. It would be simpler if you would create minimal working code which we could simply copy and test. As for me `B()` may need to convert it to HTML and laster use it with HTML component - but it would need to see it in action and it would need to create minimal working code (but we are too lazy for this)

Comment: I tried calling the class object directly in HTML components without converting it to HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `B(...)._repr_html_()` to get it as HTML and put it in streamlit using `HTML component`.

But `HTML component` can't detect its height and you have to set it manually.

```
import streamlit as st
import streamlit.components.v1 as components
from bloxs import B

st.title('Bloxs example in Streamlit')

item = B([
    B(1999, "Percent change!", percent_change=10),
    B("", "Works with emojis"),
    B("68%", "Loading progress", progress=68),
    B(1234, "Bloxs in notebook!")
])._repr_html_()

components.html(item, height=300) #, scrolling=True)
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to autofit the HTML render? I mean the height and width.

Comment: it may need to use some CSS or JavaScript. See [javascript - Make iframe automatically adjust height according to the contents without using scrollbar? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9975810/make-iframe-automatically-adjust-height-according-to-the-contents-without-using)

Comment: BTW: in [doumentation](https://docs.streamlit.io/library/components/components-api) you can see it use default height 150px but width is `"Defaults to the app's default element width."` so it shoult automatically set width to external/parent tag - and this is how most CSS frameworks work (they have predefined widths for different devices and all objects use this width)