# How to remove the scroll bar from an embed image in Google site, html

Tags: html, google-sites

I am doing a website for a dental clinic and I want to make a image slider comparison. I did it with juxtaposeJS.knightlab.com and embed the code in my Google site, but I don't know how to remove the scroll bar despite I have adjusted its height. Also, it loos horrible in mobile preview.

[the image is a screenshot of how it looks in preview mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DwgN2.png)

This is the html code:

```
<iframe frameborder="0" class="juxtapose" width="100%" height="332"
<iframe src="https://cdn.knightlab.com/libs/juxtapose/latest/embed/index.html?uid=c9bdf8aa-b4bd-11ed-b5bd-6595d9b17862"></iframe>
```

I tried Googling for other solutions I found here and on other websites but it's either the scroll bar remains there or the image disappeared after editing the HTML code.

Answer (score 0):

The code provided in the original question is not legitimate HTML, which I suspect is most of the issue.  The easiest way to fix this is probably just to give the iframe a height that is sufficient for the contained content, like this:

```html
<iframe src="https://cdn.knightlab.com/libs/juxtapose/latest/embed/index.html?uid=c9bdf8aa-b4bd-11ed-b5bd-6595d9b17862" frameborder="0" height="183"></iframe>
```

By default, [iframes have a height of 150px](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_iframe_height.asp#:%7E:text=The%20height%20attribute%20specifies%20the,default%20height%20is%20150%20pixels.), and since the image you are embedding has a hard-coded height of 183px, you are getting a scrollbar.

Alternatively, you could opt for a more dynamic JS solution, such as the one presented in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9975810/make-iframe-automatically-adjust-height-according-to-the-contents-without-using)

Comment: Thank you! This worked. Though the scroll bar still shows up in the mobile preview. Is there a way to solve this?

Answer (score -1):

Just add `scrolling="no"` in the second iframe:

```html
<iframe frameborder="0" class="juxtapose" width="100%" height="332"> </iframe>
<iframe scrolling="no" src="https://cdn.knightlab.com/libs/juxtapose/latest/embed/index.html?uid=c9bdf8aa-b4bd-11ed-b5bd-6595d9b17862"></iframe>
```