# scope external CSS file for div(no CSS file should link only )

Tags: html, css

In my page i have three CSS file

```
bootstrap.css
main.css
icon.css
```

these are the three file in my page

### Function in my page

- Am using Onload ,Onclick function
- when i click a link a external `HTML` file will load
- the external file has its own `CSS file` named `style.css`

  ### ERROR

when external file is loaded it links with `bootstarp.css` how to stop external file link with this file
external file will load in

```
<div class="page">
<!--/external file loading place-->                
</div>
```

how do i link `style.css` to the `class="page"`

- And no other CSS file should link inside`class="page"`

Comment: Why don't you copy the CSS rules of .page the linked style.css in your main.css ?

Comment: BTW, what is bootstarp ? :)

Comment: @enguerranws External file is form and when i link with style.css in main.css file totally my form design get wrong so i need to scope CSS file for div

Comment: You can't "scope" CSS file. You can select element to apply the rules to (with CSS specificity). So if you load a form in a div (e.g. with Ajax), you should put the style of this form in your main CSS file.

Comment: is it possible to post the code in fiddle, there is option in html5 using ids, but it is possible only if i see your code, or URL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that bootstrap css will always affect the conetent of divs on the entire page.

To make an area that is not affected,  you will need to load the external file into an iframe rather than a div.

Comment: when i load with iframe the iframe has vertical and hozizontal scrol bar how do i load iframe load with full with wnd height of external file

Comment: To make the iframe the same size as the containing document:  if the content you are loading is from the same domain, this should help (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9975810/make-iframe-automatically-adjust-height-according-to-the-contents-without-using)   otherwise take a look at  this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5589756/is-there-a-cross-domain-iframe-height-auto-resizer-that-works)

Answer (score 11):

You should use [Scoped Stylesheets](http://css-tricks.com/saving-the-day-with-scoped-css/) and [JQuery Scoped CSS plugin](https://github.com/thingsinjars/jQuery-Scoped-CSS-plugin) (due to current lack of browser support).

Your HTML code would look like this:

```
<div class="page">
    <style scoped>
        @import "style.css";
    </style>
    <!-- Your HTML goes here -->
</div>
```

Comment: When i try your method i get ERROR showing unexpected token IMPORT_SYM found

Comment: @user3700339, so you previously tried this method? You should have added that information to your question. Where do you get that error? From the browser Javascript console? Did you try it with the JQuery plugin I suggested?

Comment: The syntax, at least for a .Net app requires a double "@" before import. Just a heads up to those who may not know.