# Measure a web page on another domain in javascript

Tags: javascript

I need to find out the height of the web pages that go in my iframe. Those pages are out of my control and there is no way I can place code in them. I guess I could add a proxy function to my server but I'd rather avoid that if at all possible because bandwidth.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a cross-domain iframe height auto-resizer that works?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5589756/is-there-a-cross-domain-iframe-height-auto-resizer-that-works)

Answer (score 0):

If you're just trying to stretch your iframe to match your embedded content, try looking at [Make iframe automatically adjust height according to the contents without using scrollbar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9975810/make-iframe-automatically-adjust-height-according-to-the-contents-without-using)

That being said, this will NOT work for cross-domain iframes due to [Same Origin Policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy)

Comment: If you'd take a few minutes to actually read the thread, there is a link in the comments to a solution that may help.

Comment: that solution requires access to the frames source domain

Comment: Yes and without one of those two options, you cannot do this through JavaScript, as per those discussions.