# Eventbrite Embedded Widget - Mobile auto iframe height

Tags: javascript, iframe, eventbrite

I'm looking for help with Embedded Checkout code. I wish to make the `iframe` auto height for when people with on a mobile device.
Any help would be great. Code for the widget is below.

CODE

```
<div id="eventbrite-widget-container-38673272800"></div>
<script="https://www.eventbrite.com/static/widgets/eb_widgets.js">.    </script>

<script type="text/javascript">
var exampleCallback = function() {
   console.log('Order complete!');
};

window.EBWidgets.createWidget({
    // Required
   widgetType: 'checkout',
   eventId: '38673272800',
   iframeContainerId: 'eventbrite-widget-container-38673272800',

    // Optional
   iframeContainerHeight: 500,  // Widget height in pixels. Defaults to a minimum of 425px if not provided
   onOrderComplete: exampleCallback  // Method called when an order has successfully completed
});

</script>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a cross-domain iframe height auto-resizer that works?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5589756/is-there-a-cross-domain-iframe-height-auto-resizer-that-works)