# Adding custom IFrame to Wordress

Tags: html, wordpress, iframe

I am creating a website for my movie theatre. We are using a ticketing system that comes with our point of sale to offer sales online. The link is https://ticketing.useast.veezi.com/sessions/?siteToken=pxbww48zebzhba4e6yzr7f01am

I want to have this display on a page in wordpress. I don't want the scroll bar, and I want the height to fit the height of the linked content, without using a scrollbar. So if the website has 20 films with showtimes, I want the user to just scroll down on the webpage to access the info, without having a second scroll bar for the iframe.

I hope this makes sense. Also, I am hoping that there is a html snippet I can add to the page where I do not need to add code to the header to make it work. I don't want to screw around too much with the theme files themselves and this is only for one page. Thanks everyone!

Comment: https://github.com/davidjbradshaw/iframe-resizer

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5589756/is-there-a-cross-domain-iframe-height-auto-resizer-that-works

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Make Iframe to fit 100% of container's remaining height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/325273/make-iframe-to-fit-100-of-containers-remaining-height)

Comment: How about use `wp_remote_get` ? Did you tried?